# Google Chrome closes when I open a new tab using my browser action Javascript, no idea why

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm in the process of writing a Google Chrome extension, and I'm hung up on what should be a very simple task. I have a browser action that opens a popup, "popup.html", which then loads a small Javascript file, "popup.js". As soon as I get the DOMContentLoaded signal from the popup page, my Javascript opens a new tab with a certain URL. This behavioral quirk is by design - in some cases it will display a menu, and in other cases it will just open this URL.

I currently have some very simple code which is supposed to do this, but whenever it opens this tab, Chrome suddenly closes. I'm using a Mac (OS X Mavericks), so it doesn't crash entirely (still running), the window just closes. When I open it up again, the tab it was supposed to open is there, but the "popup.html" menu is awkwardly hanging over the UI still and won't go away.

Here is my complete popup.js file:

```
function stuff() {
    window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', stuff);
```

I'm guessing that I may need to gracefully close my popup window before going to this link or something, but that seems like I'm overthinking it. After all, I've seen other extensions that have normal links in their browser action popups, and you can click those to open new tabs without any Javascript magic.

I've also tried using the [chrome.tabs.create](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) function, yet the same thing happens. The Chrome developer console doesn't show any errors. Thoughts?

Edit1: Just disabled all extensions and tried again. Still breaking. Going to boot up my Windows 8 box and see what happens on it.

Edit2: Works with a short delay before opening the window now on Mac, see my answer below.

Comment: This sounds like something the popup blocker would stop... though I don't know why it would break in this particular way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I may have figured this out, but it's still weird. I did this on my Windows 8 PC, and the browser didn't crash, but the browser action popup didn't close the way it's supposed to either.

On a hunch, I altered my code on the Mac to give the browser some time to render the popup window:

```
function stuff() {
    window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}

setTimeout(stuff, 500);
```

Worked without a problem on the Mac this time. I'm guessing it's an issue with the browser being interrupted while rendering the popup window, but it's still weird. I would still appreciate an explanation from someone who actually knows what's going on here! :-)